# Edit permission on a single file. How to upload a new version of the file?

Tags: permissions, file-upload

I have a sharepoint library where only Group „Leader“ has full control permissions. A leader is sharing a file with edit permission to user A. Now user A can download the document, but how can the user upload the new version of the document. The user A can not have contribute permission on the library because otherwise he would see all files. How can user A now upload the new version of document?  Drag and Drop seems not to work (permission error). The “new document” button is missing. Who can help me??

Kind regards 
Daniel

Comment: with edit rights the user A can edit the document and save it without having to download.

Comment: The files are very huge (AutoCad Drawings,Photoshop files). Therefore they will download the file locally, make the modification and then upload the new version.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the requirements correctly or not but if you want users to collaborate why would you restrict the permissions?  One possible way would be to use content organiser and move the content from one place to correct location after the file has been uploaded.   Another way would be to create a folder and give that specific folder contribute permission.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it would do the trick:

At library level, give user A contribute permission.

Then for all of the documents in the library which you don't want user A to see, click manage permissions and break the inheritance so that the document permissions are unique from the library ie. stop inheriting permissions. Then remove user A from the document permission so he has no access to see those remaining documents.

User A will then have the ability to upload to the library, without seeing the other documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case the user would be able to add new documents. He should just be able to edit one single document.